# How do I change the name of an Armature using Python?

Tags: python, scripting

Please tell me how to change the name of an Armature using Python. For example, instead of changing Armature.001, change it to Armature, which would be without a point and without numbers. Thanks!

[image]

Answer (score 1):

`bpy.data.armatures["Armature.001"].name = "Armature"` should do the trick, but keep in mind that the ".001" was added because of an existing data-block that already had the name "Armature".

If the command is executed and the original data-block with the name "Armature" still exists, then that one will get the suffix so that the names are still unique.

Comment: Thanks! And if for example the name Armature.004 or Armature.059. Is it possible to somehow check and if the name is not Armature, then change the name to Armature?

Comment: Yes, `if arm.name != "Armature":\n    arm.name = "Armature"` will  do that.

Answer (score 0):

Found a way =)

```
for armature in bpy.data.armatures:
    armature.name = 'Armature'
```

Comment: As I mentioned in my answer, multiple armatures cannot have the same name. This solution could give unexpected results depending on what armatures are in the scene and what names they have.

Comment: I will have 1 Armature. Sometimes, during tests, when I remove the armature and add it again, the script stops working because of the armature name with numbers.